# JavaScript day difference function outputs wrong days

Tags: javascript, date

I use the following JS function to calculate the difference of days between today and a day in the future:

```
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var today = new Date();
var futureDay = new Date(futureDate);
var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((today.getTime() - futureDay.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
```

My problem: When the futureDate is today, I get the result "1" and if it is tomorrow, I get "0".

What is wrong about this function?

Comment: what is the value of futureDate?

Comment: if it was tomorrow, futureDay would be `new Date(2015,02,25)`

Comment: Your `futureDay` is initialised at midnight. Your odd rounding scheme leads to these results.

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at moment.js http://momentjs.com including a function subtract where you can get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you didn't set `future date`

```
var oneDay=1000 * 3600 * 24;
var dateToday = new Date("02/24/2015");   //or just, new Date();
var dateFuture = new Date("02/25/2015"); // set here future date like this
var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime() - dateToday.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff /oneDay); 
alert(diffDays);
```